# Running Java programs on Amazon ec2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My computer has the following version of Java:

```
 ~/a/172> java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

I wrote a fairly short program Graph.java (http://www.filedropper.com/graph_1) and compiled it into Graph.class using javac on my computer. Then I scp'd it to an Amazon Linux machine (the default one)

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-24-15 ~]$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (amzn-2.6.2.2.63.amzn1-x86_64 u91-b00)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.91-b01, mixed mode)
```

Then I tried to run it:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-24-15 ~]$ java Graph
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Graph : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: install java 8 on the machine (or compile for 7) http://serverfault.com/questions/664643/how-can-i-upgrade-to-java-1-8-on-an-amazon-linux-server maybe

Comment: This is purely a Java question. It really has nothing to do with AWS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are compiling your code with java 1.8 and trying to run on java 1.7. 
You should add following to your javac command

```
javac -source 1.7 -target 1.7
```